# Meaning of 私のことを好きにならない人が好きみたい

Tags: grammar

The sentence

> 私のことを好きにならない人が好きみたい

means "I like someone who doesn't like me back", but someone said to me that it means "I try liking someone who doesn't like me".

Which is correct?

Comment: `someone said to me` -- The *someone* is not a native speaker of Japanese, right?

Comment: yes,he is my friend

Answer (score 1):

Your friend's translation is incorrect, I'm afraid. The みたい here means "(It) looks like~~" "(It) seems like~~", not "try doing~~". <sub>(It's the auxiliary (助動詞) 「みたい(だ)」. I guess your friend is confusing it with 「te-form + みたい」, which consists of the subsidiary verb (補助動詞) 「みる」 + the auxiliary 「たい」, meaning "I want to try doing~~".)</sub>

「私のことを好きにならない人が好き（だ/です）」 (without みたい) would mean "I like someone who doesn't/won't like me back" or "I like the people who don't/won't like me back."

With the ～みたい, your sentence means:

> 私のことを好きにならない人が好き**みたい**。
>   "*It looks like* I (tend to) like someone who doesn't/won't like me back."
>   "I *seem to* like someone who doesn't/won't like me back."
>   or "*I seem* to like the people who don't/won't like me back."

Comment: It could also mean "I seem to like people/guys/girls that don't like me back", right?

Comment: @Earthliŋ Yes, the 人 can be plural, too. (この質問→ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55366/9831 で文脈を見たあとだったんで、単数だけ書いてしまいました。。)